# How to return an object where keys are inferred from input object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference

I would like to create a function in TypeScript that takes an object as a parameter, and returns another object which has the same keys. It basically should look like this from the POV of a user:

```
const foo = getBar({ baz: 23 });

console.log(foo.baz);
```

Initially, I used

```
{[ key: string ]: number }
```

as type for the parameter, but that is wrong, because this means that for every key there has to be a value (you can see that internally in `getBar`, when you try to access a value that is not there). That's why I came up with a custom implementation of `Dictionary`:

```
type Dictionary<K extends string, T> = {
  [key in K]?: T
};
```

Now the definition of the function looks like this:

```
const getBar = function
  <T extends Dictionary<string, number>>:
  Dictionary<string, number> (values: T)
{
  // ...
}
```

Now inside the function, I would like to build up the result over time, so I'm going to initialize an empty object to fill  it over time:

```
const result: Dictionary<string, number> = {};
```

When I try to run this, TypeScript complains about `{}` not being assignable to the given type. What am I missing here?

Besides, this approach also does not guarantee (from the type system's POV) that the returned dictionary has exactly the same keys as the input object. Is it possible to express this, and if so, how?

One workaround I found (but which introduces another problem) is to describe the return value as:

```
{[ key in keyof T ]: number }
```

Now from the outside it seems to work correctly, but inside the `getBar` function it is not possible any more to add items to the `result` object, since then TypeScript complains that the type `string` can not be used to index the given object type. Any hints on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve the problem with

```
const result: Dictionary<string, number> = {};
```

by using `Partial`:

```
const result: Partial<Dictionary<string, number>> = {};
```

It does mean you need a type assertion at the end when returning it, once you've filled it all the way in.

But I may be missing something (wouldn't be the first time), but I don't think you need that `Dictionary` type:

```
function getBar<T>(foo: T): T {
    let retval : Partial<T> = {};
    // ...fill in retval
    return retval as T;
}
```

Now if I do

```
const x = getBar({message: "hi"});
```

`x`'s type is `{message: string}`.

[On the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQEIEMBOAeAFQD4AKYOOALkQIEpqDEBvAWAChFEAbdRHdAG5YuiagAVcsYYSKIAvMwC+AbnacA9OsQA6XcBhcRMJPyhCuavuhA4Tg4YiwBnGqraL2EBE6iIAHvIo6Ng4JEwAtqhOTlho1ABEABYw8Yq0ykA).

Answer (score 0):

`{[ key in keyof T ]: number }` is the right answer.

And only `keyof T` can index the object of type T.

e.g. If T = `{ foo: any; baz: null; }` then `keyof T` = `'foo' | 'baz'`

If the complain of TypeScript makes you unhappy, you can avoid them in these ways:

```js
function bar<T>(obj: T) {
    let key_A = 'baz' as keyof T;
    obj[key_A]; // no error

    let key_B = 'baz'; // now the type of key_B is string
    obj[key_B]; // cannot access obj with key_B

    const key_C = 'baz'; // the type of key_C is 'baz'
    obj[key_C]; // no error

    const result = {} as any;
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        result[key] = 12345;
    });

    return result as {[ key in keyof T ]: number };
}
```